# Lack of reference to $\omega$-consistency in this proof of Gödel first incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, proof-verification, incompleteness

Is $\omega$-consistency assumed in [this proof](http://www.apronus.com/math/goedel.htm)? I understand that this proof is very informal, but then I can't seem to identify the step where $\omega$-consistency is (implicitly) used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following two passages:

> It can be proved that we can define, in terms of set theory, a function $T:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ with the following property: if $n$ is a natural number such that it encodes a theorem then $T(n) = 1$, otherwise $T(n) = 0$.

versus

> Hence $T(A(m))=1$ is a theorem. So by the property of function $T$, $A(m)$ is an encoded theorem.

There's a subtle mismatch there, between what is *true about $T$* and what is *provable about $T$*.

Going from "$T(A(m))=1$ is a theorem" to "$A(m)$ is an encoded theorem" uses $\omega$-consistency: while it is true that $T(n)$ is true iff $n$ is an encoded theorem, on what grounds can we claim that $T(n)$ is **provable in our theory** only if $n$ is an encoded theorem (which is what we need here)?

To do this, we need to assume that the things our theory proves are in fact true - or, at least, some weak version of this statement. This is exactly what $\omega$-consistency does.

Comment: Isn't $T$ defined to tell you what is provable?

Comment: @KennyLau Sure, and that's what $T$ actually does. But the theory we're talking about might prove false things about $T$.

Comment: @KennyLau: Yes, and it does so _when you interpret it in the "real world"_. But just because some statement about $T$ is _provable_ by your favorite theory doesn't automatically mean that it is _true_ -- unless you know that the theory proves only true things.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost too breezy a retelling to make sense of, but something fishy does seem to happen at the part

> Hence $T(A(m))=1$ is a theorem. So by the property of function $T$, $A(m)$ is an encoded theorem.

Here, unless I'm mistaken, the only thing we can conclude without $\omega$-consistency is that the theory under consideration *thinks* that the string $A(m)$ codes for is a theorem -- but perhaps it's wrong about what the theorems are.

That is, it is conceivable that your set theory is *consistent* and yet *has no models whose integers are standard*. (One example where this would be the case is if your favorite set theory happens to be ZFC+"ZFC is inconsistent"). And if that happens, one of the non-standard integers in the model might well be something the model *thinks* is an encoded proof of something that doesn't actually have any finite proof.

Comment: +1. And I agree, I find the whole write-up pretty unhelpful.